# Text overflow HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.comment_list li {
 min-height: 50px!important;
 position: relative;
}

.comment_list {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0px;
}

.comment_list li:nth-child(odd) { 
 background-color: #b5ffe4;
 width: 428px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #edfff8;
}

.comment_list li:nth-child(even) { 
 background-color: #95f5d2;
 width: 428px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #edfff8;
}

.comment_list li:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-bottom: 0px;
}

.comment_list::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2px;
} /* this targets the default scrollbar (compulsory) */

.comment_list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #b5ffe4;
} /* the new scrollbar will have a flat appearance with the set background color */
 
.comment_list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(27, 140, 99, 1); 
} /* this will style the thumb, ignoring the track */
 
.comment_list::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  /*  background-color: #7c2929; */
  display: none;
} /* optionally, you can style the top and the bottom buttons (left and right for horizontal bars) */
 
.comment_list::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: #b5ffe4;
} /* if both the vertical and the horizontal bars appear, then perhaps the right bottom corner also needs to be styled */

.comment_list li img {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 margin-left: 7px;
 position: relative;
}

.comment_list li span {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: underline;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.comment_list li p {
 width: 350px;
 height: 50px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; 
 font-size: 14px;
 position: absolute;
 color: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.9);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
 margin-top: 23px;
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

.comment_list li .comment_number {
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 margin-left: 355px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="comments">
      <ul class="comment_list">
       <li>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/N7aIbdn.jpg" class="comment_avatar">
        <span>X:</span>
        <span class="comment_number">#10</span>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad nulla efficiendi sit, per aeque tempor te. Cu ius quod quas invidunt. Vix omnium quaeque aliquando no, ea vis dicam consul. Ut sanctus consetetur eos, duis euismod sed et. Mea paulo eirmod voluptatum at. Et vim enim dicunt, vis ei agam vocibus lucilius.
        </p>
       </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I have is making the "li" height increase depending on the "p" size without making a fixed size. The actual page looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2p8z.png . I tried anything but no result, please help me getting an answer.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes to the following CSS:

```
.comment_list li img {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
margin-left: 7px;
float: left;
}

.comment_list li p {
width: 350px;
height: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
color: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.9);
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
margin-top: 23px;
margin-left: 12px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
display: inline-block;
float: none;
}
```

Comment: This works, I recommenced explaining what you did to achieve the effect through.

Comment: Thank you so much! There is a problem though, the "#" situated on the right side of the comments doesn't apear anymore if I add anymore "li" elements..

Comment: I removed the position absolute and the height from the paragraph tag. Using position absolute isn't good for dynamic heights. Hope this helps